# post method flask and angularJS

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

i'm new at using flask. I've been trying to do a function to handle a post request, the problem is that: in the angular controller it always goes to error or if it's not an error i can't acces to the data sent in the corresponding python function.

This is what i have:

**AngularJS controller:**

```
$http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'http://localhost:5000/holapost',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data: JSON.stringify({sent: $scope.TextToSend)
    })
      .success(function(data) {
           irrelevant....
        })
      .error(function(data) {
            irrelevant....
        });
  };
```

**python flask**

```
def post_1():
  received=request.data
  .....
  return jsonify({'msj': "what was sent was received well"})
```

Is something wrong? Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with AngularJS, but after looking through the docs at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http, you're http call looks fine.

As for Flask, make sure you are routing `post_1()` through `@app.route('/holapost')`. Regarding not being able to access the data from the post request, the flask docs recommend using the `form` attribute: `request.form`. (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object)

It would also be helpful if you ran your flask app with the debugger using: `app.run(debug=True)`. I hope this helps!